# Комбинировать две библиотеки на одном объекте

Tags: java, android

Пишу android-приложение. Мне нужно навесить на ListView 2 дополнительных функции: свайпы по элементам и перетаскивания элементов (менять местами). Есть отдельные библиотеки для свайпов и отдельные для перетаскивания (все совмещенные библиотеки, которые я видел либо не подходят, либо устарели). Вот те, которым отдаю предпочтение на данный момент:

- https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout (свайп)
- https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations (перетаскивание)

Если есть более удобные или функциональные библиотеки, буду благодарен за наводку.

Я могу отдельно сделать на своём ListView либо свайпы, либо перетаскивания, так как применение библиотеки происходит через оборачивания ListView в тип этой библиотеки. То есть на выходе имеем объект типа библиотеки, в которую обернули его (т.е. получаем кастомный ListView). А второй библиотеке нужен чистый ListView.

Вопрос в том, как мне объединить их функционал в одном ListView? Чтобы можно было и свайпы делать и перетаскивать элементы. Есть приложения, в которых это реализовано (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tasks.android).

Очень долго ищу решение в разных источниках, но ничего не могу найти. Буду крайне благодарен за конструктивные ответы и за советы, касаемые вообще реализации такой задачи.

Comment: `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` + `android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper` позволяют все самому написать как угодно. Под ваш случай библиотека вряд-ли найдется.